# Intermittent Read Timeouts to SQL Server DB - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I have a software service running via Tomcat which performs some analytics on data from my SQLServer database using the SQLServer JDBC driver.

Around 50% of the time when running SQL queries I receive the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out

I have set my connectiontimeout property in the connection strings that the software uses to connect to my database. I have also set the connection timeout within the software itself in the settings. This has no effect on the error, I set connection timeout to 120 seconds and it still throws a readtimeout within 30.

The intermittent nature of the timeouts is very strange. I'll get this error for a few minutes, and then it will work for a few minutes, refreshing easily.

Is anyone familiar with the error? Are there any more settings I could set in the connection string to try and resolve the readtimeout as it seems to be a different thing to connectiontimeout.

Comment: The SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't have a connection property `connectiontimeout` according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). I am not sure if there is a way to control this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi, it is not in the jdbc settings that I have added the property. It is in the conenction string the JDBC driver uses to connect to the data source. It's such a difficult thing to disgnose, if I knew exactly what the error meant it would be a start...

Comment: Perhaps you should try out the [JTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/), I found it to be superior to MS's driver.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I say: the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't seem to have such a connection property (the thing you add to the JDBC url is a connection property(!)), so setting it is not going to have an effect.

Comment: What you're hitting sounds like the `commandTimeout` behaviour in ODBC/ADO.NET. The `connectionTimeout` affects how long a client will wait to establish a connection to a server. Once connected the `commandTimeout` affects how long the client waits for the response to a query. You might be able to use the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc driver's `queryTimeout` and `cancelQueryTimeout` settings to achieve a similar result, [Setting the Connection Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties)

Comment: This may be something not related to Java JDBC .. i.e. you might find that SSMS and apps not using JDBC also encounter this error. I've got the case where all apps (SSMS, Delphi app using SDAC, JDBC ...) they all hit this error after 3.5 hours of connectivity.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/afb47f41-5196-4e30-8213-d72cddb79641/sqlexception-read-timed-out-clientconnectionidf9c1a8c4326a4945a166e0c906bfe4e5?forum=sqlgetstarted